# How to create a flycheck checker that could be enabled in every mode?

Tags: flycheck

I want to create a checker that shows strings like "TODO" in flycheck error list.

Since this checker works on text, it can be applied to any major mode. But when creating the checker with `flycheck-define-generic-checker` I need to specify the complete list of modes.

At this moment, I compute a list of modes from the modes of `flycheck-checkers`, but I wonder if there is a better approach.

I have tried to define a `:predicate` in my checker, but it is tested after the list of applicable modes.

A special mode like `all-modes`, maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the `major-mode` on demand to your checker in `flyspell-mode-hook` with `(cl-pushnew major-mode (flycheck-checker-get 'flycheck-todo 'modes))`. Note, that `flyspell-add-mode` is not so ideal since it adds modes repeatedly when you open multiple buffers with the same `major-mode`.

For demonstration, I define a `flycheck-todo` checker below. The function `flycheck-todo-add` for `flycheck-mode-hook` at the end of the source snippet adds the checker `flycheck-todo`.

The checker `flycheck-todo` cannot run parallel to the other checkers registered for the major mode.

But you can chain it to the other checkers. This is done by running `flycheck-add-next-checker` for the checker returned by `flycheck-get-checker-for-buffer`.

I have positively tested that the checker works with `org-mode`, `cc-mode`, `python-mode` and `lisp-mode`. But, it does not work with `emacs-lisp-mode`. I do not know why. Perhaps, someone else can shed some light on this.

```el
;; -*- lexical-binding: t -*-
(require 'cl-lib)

(defvar flycheck-todo-debug nil
  "Emit debug messages for flycheck-todo.")

(defun flycheck-todo-start (checker callback)
  "Just search for TODO."
  (when flycheck-todo-debug
    (message "Starting flycheck-todo"))
  (let ((buffer (current-buffer)))
    (make-thread
     (lambda ()
       "Search for all TODOs and report them via CALLBACK"
       (condition-case err
       (with-current-buffer buffer
         (save-excursion
           (when flycheck-todo-debug
         (message "Running TODO-CHECKER."))
           (save-match-data
         (goto-char (point-min))
         (let (data
               case-fold-search) ;; case sensitive search
           (while (re-search-forward "\\<TODO\\>" nil t)
             (push
              (flycheck-error-new-at-pos
               (match-beginning 0)
               'info ;; level
               "Flycheck-todo discovered TODO." ;; no error message
               :id 'todo ;; id
               :end-pos (match-end 0))
              data)
             )
           (when flycheck-todo-debug
             (message "Data of TODO-CHECKER: %s" data))
           (funcall callback 'finished data)
           ))))
       (flycheck-todo-canceled
        (funcall callback 'interrupted nil))
       (error
        (message "Flycheck-todo error: %s" err))
       ))
     "flycheck-todo") ;; the returned thread is the context object
    ))

(defun flycheck-todo-interrupt (checker context)
  "Interrupt the idle timer for highlighting TODO."
  (when (and (eq checker 'flycheck-todo)
         (thread-live-p context))
    (when flycheck-todo-debug
      (message "Cancel flycheck-todo-timer %s." context))
    (thread-signal context 'flycheck-todo-canceled nil)))

(flycheck-define-generic-checker
    'flycheck-todo
  "Report TODO."
  :start #'flycheck-todo-start
  :interrupt #'flycheck-todo-interrupt
  :modes 'text-mode ;; Dummy.
  )

(add-to-list 'flycheck-checkers 'flycheck-todo t)

(defun flycheck-todo-add ()
  "Insert `flycheck-todo' to flycheck chain of current buffer."
  (cl-pushnew major-mode (flycheck-checker-get 'flycheck-todo 'modes))
  (when-let ((checker (flycheck-get-checker-for-buffer))
         ((null (eq checker 'flycheck-todo))))
    (flycheck-add-next-checker checker 'flycheck-todo t)))

(add-hook 'flycheck-mode-hook #'flycheck-todo-add)
```

Comment: Your code works in my case, buy finally I used another aproach and I bundled it in a package: [https://github.com/alvarogonzalezsotillo/flycheck-hl-todo/](https://github.com/alvarogonzalezsotillo/flycheck-hl-todo/)